# Execute Stored Procedure with RollbackTrans using VBA and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, transactions, vba

I would like to execute an insert stored procedure using VBA Excel but I have some problem. Basically, I want to insert 100 rows of same data by executing the stored procedure 10 times with ability to rollback the transaction.

- If I execute VBA run my VBA code with out For Loop then my VBA code is run fine, no error
- When I insert For Loop then I get an error indicate I have too many agreements. I tried to move the For Loop around but the problem can't be solved.

> Procedure or function Sample has too many arguments specified.
>   -2147217900  Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.      3704

My question: how can I run the insert stored procedure with ability to rollback the transaction? Or will I have to edit the `Rollback Trans` in my SQL Server stored procedure ~~> if so, how can I rewrite my code to execute the new SQL?

I have a table `Test.Sample`:

```
Create Table Test.Sample
(
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Col1 varchar(10),
    Col2 varchar(10)
)
```

with the following stored procedure to insert the data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample
    @Col1 varchar(10),
    @Col2 varchar(10)
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [Test].[Sample] (Col1, Col2)
    VALUES (@Col1, @Col2)
```

When I run a single insert, then the following code work fine

```
Private Sub Test()
                    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
                    Dim cm As ADODB.Command
                    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
                    Set cm = New ADODB.Command
                    Dim pm As ADODB.Parameter
                    Dim i As Integer
On Error GoTo 1
                    con.Open connString
                    con.BeginTrans
'For i = 1 To 10 ~~~~ code will return an error if this is active
                    With cm
                    .ActiveConnection = con
                    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                    .CommandText = "sales.spInsertSalesRequestPart"
                        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Col1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "TEST")
                        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Col2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "TEST")
                        .Execute
                   End With

'Next i
                   con.CommitTrans
                   con.Close
                   Exit Sub

1:
        With con
            con.RollbackTrans
            con.Close
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post actual error number and description? Also, try wrapping `For` loop outside begin and commit transaction.

Comment: @Parfait I added the err code, however, assume it worked when I put the for loop before the BeginTrans and next after CommitTrans, would it defeat the purpose of RollbackTrans?

Comment: I'm surprised that the code works even when executing it once, as you have two parameters called "@Col1" and none called "@Col2".  But maybe it doesn't really care what the name is (I've never used parameters, so I'm definitely no expert!), although I suspect that having 4 parameters on the second time through the loop (and 20 by the time you get to the 10th time through the loop) is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @yowE3K, it was  a typo

Comment: If the duplication of "Col1" was a typo, then I'm now convinced that your problem is that your loop is first passing 2 parameters (which works) then passing 4 parameters (which fails) then passing 6 parameters, etc, while the stored procedure is only wanting 2 parameters.  So you need to delete the existing parameters before adding new ones, or else just use `.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Test].[Sample] (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('" & valOfCol1 & "', '" & valOfCol2 & "')"` (where valOfCol1 and valOfCol2 are string variables containing the values you want to pass).

Comment: Excellent point @YowE3K! I added an answer to that effect with your credit. And yes, to OP, you would want to place transaction outside loop so if any error occurs rollback all queued changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use same parameters then you can use the the transaction in sql procedure itself and do the looping

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample
@Col1 varchar(10),
@Col2 varchar(10)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

begin tran
declare @i int = 1
while @i <= 10 
begin
INSERT INTO [Test].[Sample] (Col1, Col2)
VALUES (@Col1, @Col2)
set @i=@i+1
end
commit tran
```

But i am sure you might have different variables to pass for each loop from your vb or c# in that case you can package all into a table variable and pass it as a single table variable and you can do the transaction within sproc

Comment: yes, the sample code is just for the purpose of simplifying the problem, each time volume of Col1 and Col2 will be different. Too bad I am limited to VBA Excel only.

Answer (score 0):

Consider resetting the command object, `cmd` with each iteration. As @YowE3K comments you are increasingly appending parameters to each call and hence the error *too many arguments*:

```vb
...
con.BeginTrans

For i = 1 To 10
    Set cm = New ADODB.Command

    With cm
       .ActiveConnection = con
       .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
       .CommandText = "sales.spInsertSalesRequestPart"
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Col1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "TEST")
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Col2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "TEST")
       .Execute
    End With

Next i

con.CommitTrans
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out before and saw my doctor a few hours ago.